# Moodle SQL - Creating Filter with 2 user profile fields data

Tags: mysql, moodle

New to this moodle sql using configurable reports plugin.

```
SELECT u.username AS 'User name',
u.firstname AS 'First name',
u.lastname AS 'Last Name',
c.fullname AS 'Course',
u.department AS 'department',
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.timeenrolled),'%m/%d/%Y') AS 'Enrollment Date',
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.timecompleted),'%m/%d/%Y') AS 'Completion Date',
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.timecompleted),INTERVAL 1 YEAR), '%Y-%m-%d') AS 'Expiration Date' 

FROM prefix_course_completions AS p
JOIN prefix_course AS c ON p.course = c.id
JOIN prefix_user AS u ON p.userid = u.id

WHERE 1 = 1
%%FILTER_SUBCATEGORIES:cc.path%% 
%%FILTER_COURSES:Course%%
%%FILTER_USERS:Department%%
%%FILTER_SEARCHTEXT:u.firstname:~ %%
ORDER BY u.firstname
```

Is there a way where I can Filter the search text using first name and last name?

Like: `%%FILTER_SEARCHTEXT:u.firstname:~ + u.lastname:~ %%` or should I CONCAT them to make this work? Haven't found anything about this in moodle community and configurable reports documentation.

Answer (score 1):

CONCAT works for me ;)

```
%%FILTER_SEARCHTEXT:CONCAT (u.firstname, ' ',u.lastname):~%%
```